# Jenkins build Groovy exist error Unable to load class hudson.model.Hudson due to missing dependency

Tags: jenkins, groovy

I am beginner in Groovy and Jenkins. I try to start a job as Freestyle project

 I added **Buid > Add build step > Execute groovy script** and type code like this

```
#!/usr/bin/env groovy
import hudson.model.*
import hudson.AbortException
import hudson.console.HyperlinkNote
import java.util.concurrent.CancellationException
// Start another job
def job = Hudson.instance.getJob('mhi_job_test2')
def anotherBuild
try {
    //def future = job.scheduleBuild()
    println "Waiting for the completion of " + job.url + "\nName:"+job.fullDisplayName // HyperlinkNote.encodeTo('/' + job.url, job.fullDisplayName)
    //anotherBuild = future.get()
} catch (CancellationException x) {
    throw new AbortException("${job.fullDisplayName} aborted.")
}
```

I try run script by link http://localhost:8080/script . it is working well

**But there are a error Missing dependency**

> [job_decision] $ D:path-to-groovy-home\groovy-2.4.7\bin\groovy.bat 
>  D:path-to-jenkin\Jenkins\workspace\job_decision\jenkin.groovy
>   org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed:
>   General error during class generation: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Unable to load class hudson.model.Hudson due to missing dependency hudson/remoting/VirtualChannel 
>   java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Unable to load class hudson.model.Hudson due to missing dependency hudson/remoting/VirtualChannel

Comment: Looks like you need to use `System groovy script` step instead.

Comment: Thanks @izzekil, i changed to use System groovy script. the issues was resolved.